# Does logistic regression with LASSO require smaller samples to train in comparison with regular logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, regularization, regression-strategies

The question is within the title.

Comment: I think it would be relevant to specify what the sample size is required for. For achieving the same predictive accuracy? Or for what?

Comment: I mean dimensionality reduction property of this type of regularization

Comment: This is not precise enough, at least for me. What are you actually comparing? Regular logistic regression with all features in does not offer any dimensionality reduction regardless of sample size...

Answer (score 4):

You have to define "regular".  If regular logistic regression means fitting a well-thought out completely pre-specified model, then logistic regression requires a lower sample size.  If you are doing feature selection (usually not recommended) then the penalization that is part of *lasso* keeps the method honest, whereas stepwise regression with unpenalized ordinary logistic regression doesn't work very well.  But some of the apparent advantages of *lasso* are illusory: bootstrapping may reveal that the list of features "selected" by *lasso* is very unstable.

Comment: Thank you very much! By "regular" I mean logistic regression trained on the whole number of features (not pre-selected)

Comment: I think it would be relevant to specify what the sample size is required for, first in the OP but then also in the answer.

Comment: And I also mean situation where number of samples is about the same size as number of features. Is lasso helpful in this case? (I know about random subspace method and others)

Comment: Yes, and L2 norm (quadratic penalty) can work even better since it doesn't require feature selection.